# Loop is not terminating, please someone explain what am doing wrong

Tags: c++, loops, vector

**I can't find out, why this loop is not terminating. please someone explain. What am I doing wrong.**

```
std::vector<int> vec{};
int result{0};

for (unsigned i = 0; i < vec.size() - 1; i++) {
    for (unsigned j = i + 1; j < vec.size(); j++) {
        result += vec.at(i) * vec.at(j);
    }
}
std::cout << result;
```

I wanted to find out sum of the product of integers pairs in vector. eg: for `{1, 2, 3}`, `result` should be `(1 * 2) + (1 * 3) + (2 * 3)`, it works fine. But for edge case like when vector is empty, it doesn't show result instead, it runs forever.

Comment: Print `vec.size() - 1` and you may get a surprise! It's **huge** because `size_t` `0 - 1` becomes the largest `unsigned`value possible for a `size_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vec.size()` returns an **unsigned** type, so `size() - 1` will wrap around to a very large value if `size()` is 0. You don't need the `- 1` in the first place, since your inner loop already handles the edge cases where pairs of integers are not available to multiply.

You also don't need the overhead of `vec.at(index)` since your loops are doing adequate bounds checking on their own, so you can use `vec[index]` instead.

Try this:

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec{};
int result{0};

for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
    for (size_t j = i + 1; j < vec.size(); ++j) {
        result += vec[i] * vec[j];
    }
}
std::cout << result;
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/3lKPtv)

Answer (score 2):

`vec.size() - 1` when `vec.size()` is `0`, as it is in your example, will become the largest `std::vector<int>::size_type` (`size_t`) possible. `size_t` is `unsigned`, so negative values "wrap" around to start at the largest positive value instead.

A possible fix is to check if `vec` is empty before looping:

```
if (!vec.empty()) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vec.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (unsigned j = i + 1; j < vec.size(); j++) {
            result += vec[i] * vec[j]; // no need for bounds checking here
        }
    }
}
```